# How to insert output of a command at a specific line?

Tags: sed

Let's say I have a file called `CHANGELOG.md`, and that I want to *insert* the output of a `generate-changelog` command at line 4. How can I achieve this with shell commands such as `sed`?

## The file I need to change

```bsh
$ cat CHANGELOG.md
# Change Log
All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.
This project adheres to [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/).

# 3.0.0
…
```

## The command I have

```bsh
$ generate-changelog
# 3.0.1
- fixed some bug
- lots and lots 
- of multiline
- output
```

## The result I would like to obtain (not on stdout, in `CHANGELOG.md` directly)

```
# Change Log
All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.
This project adheres to [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/).

# 3.0.1
- fixed some bug
- lots and lots 
- of multiline
- output

# 3.0.0
…
```

Basically, I need to make this static command based on stdin (I need to be able to *insert* arbitrary content, provided by a command at line 4):

```bsh
sed -i "4a\
    ## [$newTag](https://github.com/$(repo_path)/compare/$(latest_tag)...$newTag) - $(today)" CHANGELOG.md
```

Comment: That's irrelevant, I want the output of that command, be it a file or shell built-in

Comment: Does this help? [Using sed to insert file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243102/using-sed-to-insert-file-content)

Comment: At least with GNU sed (and assuming your command writes to stdout), you could try `generate-changelog | sed -i '4r/dev/stdin' CHANGELOG.md`

Comment: @steeldriver please post this as an answer so that I can award you points for it, it works great!

Comment: @greg0ire thanks - done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least with GNU sed, you can use the `r` command with a special file name `/dev/stdin` to read and queue the contents of standard input for insertion at the end of the cycle (`r` is kind of like an `a` for files).

So assuming your `generate-changelog` writes to standard output, you can try

```
generate-changelog | sed -i '4r/dev/stdin' CHANGELOG.md
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I hoped for, just couldn't find the right syntax, yet it remains fairly simple and plays well with pipes. Great job!

Comment: Note that for this to work, file to be edited in place must contain text at least up to the line before the one specified as insertion point. This is, if text is to be inserted at line 4, then, file should have some text inserted line 3 (or more)

Answer (score 1):

Like this with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'NR==4{system("generate-changelog")}1' file
```

you need temporary file with IO redirections for this to work.

Comment: I need the output of `generate-changelog`, not literally `generate-changelog` itself

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: I don't want the contents of `generate-changelog`, I want the output generated by that command.

Comment: Simply removed the 'cat', should works now

Comment: For my use case it doesn't the command in question is interactive, and I don't get a chance to input anything…

Comment: Then edit and clarify your question

Comment: Actually I think I got confused, I think it kind of works, but it outputs instead of inserting in the file as asked in the question.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace _in place_ or _on the fly_ ?

Comment: I think I mean in place, just like my primitive `sed -i` does in the example I gave at the end of the question.